# Hibernate Second Level Cache Not Getting Updated

Tags: hibernate, memcached

I made an application in Hibernate 3.2 and did second level caching on my entities using memcached.

The problem I am facing is that once the entities have been cached, if I update any entity item that was cached, it is not being updated.

My use case is:
Steve has his son name as Jon.

Now, I load the entity for Steve from database along with which I get his son's entity also which is Jon. But when I do an update on name of Jon to 'Marc', the same change does not get reflected when I load the entity having Steve again.

I think memcached has have it cached and when I update it, the entity does not get refreshed.

I need to update this entity on change, i.e. whenever an entity has any field update, the same entity is refreshed in the cache with the updates.

Please help. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

If the update is performed through nHibernate the cache will get updated, if it is done outside of nHibernate (e.g. through the database direct) then nHibernate will not be aware of the change so when you reload from cache it will not have any updated value.

How are you updating the name?

Comment: I updated the name directly by firing a database query and my requirement is this only, i want that change is detected by the cache if any update happens from outside of Hibernate.